# Hide Debian OS file system navigation through browser while download/upload

Tags: javascript, html, linux, browser, x11

I am working on Debian Linux in embedded system. For display I am using chromium in kiosk mode. While navigating to upload/download via chromium browser, user can see all file system of Linux as its default navigation.

Is there method to prevent that navigation and limit it to only /media only, so that end user cannot know about OS and cannot modify critical data of OS.

Any suggestion very helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run the browser under a user ID that has no access to anything other than the directories you choose.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have doubts If I set like that how can the user access X11 diectories which are required in login manager, clearing cache etc.

Comment: And also we cannot hide root directories under /. Hence user can see the root directories. Requirement is like not to navigate any directory of Linux only content of  /media/ except restrict write permission.